# how to generate javascript embed code

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

how to generate embd code/blgger like widget with CodeIgniter? please give me the idea how to make

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say your widget html is rendered as an iframe.

For e.g.

```
<iframe src='http://somedomain/.../some-widget'></iframe>
```

Now, your embed code could be as simple as:

```
<script src="http://yourdomain/.../something.js"></script>
```

All you have to do inside something.js is :

```
document.write("<iframe src='http://somedomain/.../some-widget'></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating any front-end code in CI is no different than regular PHP. Simply echo the html where you wish it to be. If you were a little more specific, I could help you more..

Answer (score 0):

Using an iframe is the simplest solution. Hand out the iframe code to your users.

```
<iframe src="your url here"></iframe>
```

Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/vXu8a/

Comment: well, if i wanted to get solution as like http://jsfiddle.net/vXu8a/1/

<script src="http://myonepage.com/eyoosuf/widgets/card.js" type="text/javascript"></script>​

how to proceed?